# NFS Service not enabed`

Tags: lubuntu, nfs

I am trying to run the NFS service on ubuntu 16.04, but when i run command:

```
Sudo service nfsd status
```

I get following message:

```
millionlights@millionlights-desktop:~$ sudo service nfsd status
[sudo] password for millionlights: 
● nfsd.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
 Active: inactive (dead)
```

I ran commands below to to install nfs server and client but in vain.

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

Please tell me how can i make nfs client run?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the systemd service is not `nfsd` (that's the name of the daemon *process*):

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files nfs*
UNIT FILE                 STATE   
nfs-blkmap.service        static  
nfs-config.service        static  
nfs-idmapd.service        static  
nfs-kernel-server.service enabled 
nfs-mountd.service        static  
nfs-server.service        enabled 
nfs-utils.service         static  
nfs-blkmap.target         disabled
nfs-client.target         enabled 

9 unit files listed.
```

So the command to show the server status is

```
systemctl status nfs-server
```

or

```
systemctl status nfs-kernel-server
```

Comment: Thanks. IT shows nfs-server, services running but my ultimate goal is to get the nfsd client running. And when i use command to do it: sudo nfsd start....it gives output as: sudo: nfsd: command not found
Please help me getting nfsd client running on mu ubuntu.

Comment: @ChandrashekharPatil sorry I am not familiar with any "nsfd client" - can you provide a link to any instructions that you are following?

Comment: Sorry for late reply...but this is the step i am asked to do.                    sudo nfsd status
(nfsd service is enabled)
(nfsd is running (pid 313, 8 threads))

Comment: Thanks for reply. Below is thing i am asked to do   :                                       sudo nfsd status
nfsd service is enabled
nfsd is running (pid 313, 8 threads)          otherwise start service ...   sudo nfsd start
(Starting the nfsd service)

Comment: @steeldriver: Thanks for reply... I was unable to find the answer in the documentation